# How to make <li> elements dynamically adjust to fill entire width of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Say I have four `<li>` elements that take up `width:25%` each of the entire document window.  If I wanted to use jQuery-UI resizable() to resize these elements, how can I ensure that their width always adds up to 100%?  Such that, if I shrink one of the elements' width, an adjacent element makes up for it?

I have this fiddle as a work in progress: http://jsfiddle.net/kVwRC/6/show/

And this demo as what I'm working towards: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way your could do it.

It's using css table behaviour to ensure all space is divided up by each panel and js to manage the adjustments of each panel's width.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="handle"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="handle"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="handle"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/CuqJr/show

Comment: Is there a way to make this solution work for touch events? Forgot to mention that touch is a requirement (iOS/Android)

Comment: I used the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events in that demo. You could try adding `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar with divs to create the kind of layout you are trying to make here. I have made a plugin named [jSplit](https://code.google.com/p/jsplit/source/browse/trunk/jsplit.js) out of it and the code uploaded at Google Code. You can go ahead and take a look.

The idea is to calculate the width/height of adjacent elements when the user drags the slider.